# Combining and Adding Array Values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structured like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.0.result
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.0.result
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.0.result
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.1.result
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.1.result
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.1.result
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
        )
)
```

What I would like is the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.0.result
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => cmi.interactions.1.result
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 0
        )
)
```

Basically I want to know how to find where the first value in each subarray match and add the second and third value accordingly?

Comment: Seems pretty doable, what code do you have that tries to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, did not check it

```
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $el)
  if (!isset($out[$el[0]]))
     $out[$el[0]] = $el;
  else
     for($i = 1; $i < count($el); $i++)
        $out[$el[0]][$i] += $el[$i];
```

You can remove keys after that, like `$out = array_values($out);`

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can use the following algorithm :-

1. Sort your array
2. Iterate over your array, and keep track of your array if the 0th element has changed.
3. Maintain the 2 sums in 2 different variables.

Below is a hint to the algorithm. I did not test it, so, it may not work fully. But this should give you a good hint to carry on.

```
$prevValue="";
$sum1=0;
$sum2=0;
$index=0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if($prevValue==$value[0])
    {
        if(value[1]==1)
            $sum1++;
        if(value[2]==1)
            $sum2++;
    }else{
        $ansArr[$index]=array($value[0], $sum1,$sum2);
    }

    $prevValue=$value[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go.  We build that second array as $a2 and add elements to it and accumulate the sums into it.  Tested it on your values ok.

```
function parse($a)
{
    $a2 = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($a); $i++) {
        $isFound = false;
        for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < sizeof($a2); $i2++) {
            if ($a[$i][0] == $a2[$i2][0]) {
                // We've already run into this search value before
                // So add the the elements
                $isFound = true;
                $a2[$i2][1] += $a[$i][1];
                $a2[$i2][2] += $a[$i][2];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$isFound) {
            // No matches yet
            // We need to add this one to the array
            $a2[] = $a[$i];
        }
    }
    return $a2;
}
```